# replace word to another in the text regex

Tags: regex, perl

```
some text and some text too bad,
some too&nbsp; bad again some bad
and other words bad, it is too       bad
```

i am trying to replace all word "bad" to "good", but there is exception:

if word "too" precedes "bad", "bad" should not be changed to "good",
there can be one or mote whitespace between "too" and "bad", even html whitespace " "

So after regex manipulation text should be

```
    some text and some text too bad,
    some too&nbsp; bad again some good
    and other words good, it is too       bad
```

Tried something like this, but it does not work properly.

```
$text ~= s/(too(\s+|\s*&nbsp;\s*))bad/good/ig;
```

Please help

Comment: Although regex experts can do wonders, at the end somebody has to understand and maintain such code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to decode `html` whitespaces, and apply a regular expression that evaluates if the preceding string is `too`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    _decode_entities($_, { nbsp => "\xA0" }); 
    s/(\w+)(\s+)bad/$1 eq 'too' ? $& : "$1$2good"/eg;
    encode_entities($_);
    print $_; 
}

__DATA__
some text and some text too bad,
some too&nbsp; bad again some bad
and other words bad, it is too       bad
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
some text and some text too bad,
some too&nbsp; bad again some good
and other words good, it is too       bad
```

Comment: So a non-breakable space becomes breakable?

Comment: @Borodin: Thank you for noticing the bug. I've added the `encode_entities()` function to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Borodin and @Birei, it really helped

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done conveniently using a regular expression. It is made even more complex because the idea of a *word* isn't clear: for instance, you want to treat "bad," as the word "bad".

This program working by tokenising the string into words and separators, then changing all occurrences of "bad" to "good" unless they are preceded by "too" (ignoring upper and lower case). I have included comma, colon, and semicolon in your list of possible separators. You may want to tweak this to get the results you expect.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = <<END;
some text and some text too bad,
some too&nbsp; bad again some bad
and other words bad, it is too       bad 
END

my @tokens = split /((?:[\s,;.:]|&nbsp;)+)/, $text;

for my $i (grep { lc $tokens[$_] eq 'bad' } 1 .. $#tokens) {
  $tokens[$i] = 'good' unless lc $tokens[$i-2] eq 'too';
}

print join '', @tokens;
```

**output**

```
some text and some text too bad,
some too&nbsp; bad again some good
and other words good, it is too       bad
```